# TinyMCE and output with MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I have set my database to utf8, all my files is using utf8 as charset, but my insert from tinymce is html entities(&lt;p&gt;Jabbathehut&lt;/p&gt;rn&a...)
I'm trying to print out so b, strong, p, etc is working. But i only get plain text like this: https://i.gyazo.com/bfc1c3a7ba7d22ae4673202939ab0046.png
I have tried several solutions: etc `htmlspecialchars($htmlsanitize, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

```
$getProgress = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_comments WHERE article = $number AND userid = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'"); 
while($progressinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getProgress)) 
{           
    echo '<h4><b>Din besvarelse</b></h4>
'.htmlspecialchars_decode($progressinfo['comment']).'';
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the data your DB, does it contain entities or tags?

Comment: @atoms
Image of insert: https://i.gyazo.com/3cf236571a5dd296746fc4d16c4d4918.png

Comment: Try using html_entity_decode()

Comment: it looks like they are being inserted as entities. What are you doing to the data before its inserted? I suggest you echo out the data your sending to the content column and update your answer with it

Comment: Please don't use the old `mysql` extension...use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to perform your insert is using PDO's, the same can and should be done for your select statement.

I would imagine using this method would resolve any issues relating to the inserting of converted entities into your DB.

```
// define allowed tags
define('ALLOWED_TAGS', '<p>,<strong>,<ul>,<li>,<ol>,<em><br>');

$sContent = '';

// if form has been posted
if(isset($_POST['Create'])){

    // Read content from WYSIWYG
    if(isset($_POST['Article']) && $_POST['Article'] != ''){

        if(strlen(strip_tags($_POST['Article'], ALLOWED_TAGS)) > 10 ){

            $sArticle = strip_tags($_POST['Article'], ALLOWED_TAGS);

        }else $sError .= "[ArticleLength]";

    }
    if($sArticle == "") $sError .= "[Article]";


    // nothing in error string. proceed to insert
    if($sError == ''){

        // create an instance of the connection
        $conn   = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

        // prepare the sql
        $sSQL = "INSERT INTO cms_comments (Article, col2) VALUES (:Article, :col2)";
        $st   = $conn->prepare( $sSQL );

        // bind the input vars
        $st->bindValue(":Article", $sArticle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindValue(":col2", $col2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the tinymce.init file. You can set entity_encoding to `raw` which means characters will be stored in non-entity form except the XML default entities: 
  `& < > "`

```
tinymce.init({
....
entity_encoding : "raw"
```

per:https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#encodingtypes